# PHP SQL order by multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table called 'scorelist' with the following results:

```
ID   USER_ID   SCORE   SEASON
-----------------------------
1    1         35      3
2    1         45      2
3    2         80      3
4    2         85      1
5    3         65      2
```

I want to make a score list where I show the scores of the users but only of their last played season.
Result should be:

```
ID   USER_ID   SCORE   SEASON
-----------------------------
3    2         80      3
5    3         65      2
1    1         35      2
```

I use the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM scorelist 
WHERE season = (
    SELECT season FROM scorelist ORDER BY season DESC LIMIT 1
) 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

But then I only get the results of season 3, so a lot of users are not shown.
I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM scorelist group by user_id ORDER BY score DESC, season DESC
```

But this is also not working.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: *I use the following code* ща course, you got last season at all, over all users, whereas last season differs for each separate user. *I also tried* The query have incomplere grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use window function row_number to solve this problem:

```
WITH ordered_scorelist AS (
    SELECT 
        scorelist.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by USER_ID order by SEASON DESC) rn 
    FROM scorelist
) SELECT 
    USER_ID, SCORE, SEASON 
FROM ordered_scorelist 
WHERE rn = 1 
ORDER BY SCORE DESC;
```

[MySQL row_number test](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=28f00db04e48a708c7046850050d17bb&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Thanks!
Is it also possible to use a range of the 3 latest seasons? So that users who have not participated for a long time are not shown.

Comment: Yes, it possible. Look here: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=21b956d5184164a7f8db714c8f79c3c2&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80

Comment: You are the best. It works, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The subquery gets the latest season for each user. If you join to that you get your desired results

```
SELECT s1.* 
FROM scorelist s1
JOIN 
(
   SELECT user_id, max(season) AS season
   FROM scorelist
   GROUP BY user_id
) s2 ON s1.user_id = s2.user_id AND s1.season = s2.season
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was indeed the solution.